# Capturing screenshot of div element in extJS

Tags: java, d3.js, extjs, screenshot

We have a java based application which is using extJS and charts rendered using d3JS. We have a requirement of capturing Screenshot of a div element on our webpage.

For this, We have tried below options :

Html2Canvas - we are unable to use it because of extJS conflicts.

Java AWT  - This captures server side screenshot. We need to capture the client side screen(particular div element on the page).

Can anyone suggest a solution for the above problem (in any technology which can be integrated with extJs, d3JS, Java)?

Comment: Which ExtJs conflicts? And, since you want clientside, Java tag is not relevant, unless you actually run Java code on your clients.

Comment: @ M. Prokhorov  -  Thanks for responding. 
We are facing issue with ext-all-debug-w-comments js file. 

In html2canvas we have Image class which is a js class and it returns image but here  ext-all-debug-w-cmnt js is overriding and returning image as constructor. So images are not rendering.
Instead of html2canvas can we have any clinet side technoloy to capture  ?